# Why does this code only work in certain JS executors?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

This code takes an integer and returns the amount of 1s that are present.

```js
function countOnes(i) {
let str  = i.toString();
let ones = 0;
for(let x = 0; x < i.length; x++) {
  if(str.charAt(x) === '1') ones++;
 }
return ones;
}

console.log(countOnes(111000));
```

But it only appears to work in certain executors of JavaScript. If I enter this code into [p5.js](https://editor.p5js.org/) or [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString), I will receive the desired output of `3`.

But if I use the console in my browser and some other websites emulating that, `0` will be returned with every given value.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Your code has a typo: `i.length()` should be `str.length` — you have to get the length of the *string*, not the original number. (Numbers don't have a `.length` property, so that'd come out `undefined`.)

Comment: Also it's a mystery to me what you mean by "enter this code into p5.js or Mozilla MDN". Where exactly did you "enter" it? The code should not work in any JavaScript environment.

Comment: That `i.length` needs to be `str.length` for the code to work. Maybe you just wrote the right variable when using one of those online repls?

Comment: well not `.length()` @Pointy

Comment: Yes yes sorry I fixed the comment. For what it's worth at the p5.js "playground" site this logs 0, which is what one would expect. Lol I'm on my laptop and I haven't zoomed in the page so It's all just little squiggles

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=let is the browser in question supported?

Comment: @Pointy I really have no idea. I remember writing the code in the MDN JS demo box and it logged 3; I copy and pasted it into p5 and it did the same, but when I pasted it into console it logged 0. But now, when I copy and paste the code in this post into any of the aforementioned environments, they *all* log 0. So I have no clue how that works.

Comment: As an addition, I replaced `i.length` with `str.length` but the problem persists.

Comment: How can "the problem persist" if you also say it's logging 0 in all cases? It logs 0 because of the `.length` error. If you use `str.length` it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. you cant loop on **i.length**, **i** its still a 'Number' type,
   you should loop on "str.length" instead.
2. you better give more meaningful names... **i** should be **num**,
   **str** should be **numStr**, **ones** should be **counter**.

try this:

```
function countOnes(num) {
    var counter = 0;
    var numsArray = Array.from((num + ''))
    numsArray.forEach(num => {
        return (num == 1)? counter++ : ''
    })
    return counter
}   
console.log(countOnes(1110010)); // 4
```